# Implementation of planets in top-down space shooter

Tags: 2d, game-design, game-mechanics, physics

I am working on a top-down space shooter, and I have come to the point where I need some input on a mechanic. I have implemented enough that I can make this choice; either way will not change the code in any major fashion.

Which would be a more interesting feature: Having planets being among the 2d objects that the ships interact with (crashing into, being able to have batteries that fire from them); or should they be background objects, maybe still having effects on the battle, but less of a direct influence.

Practical differences: Would the planets have gravity (first yes, second maybe not)? Would they take up space (first yes, second no)?
Any other differences that might affect the differences, please let me know.

Comment: The question is really vague. Aren't you basically asking "what game do you think I should make"?

Comment: This isn't the place for polls. This would be a great question for chat and you have the rep to ask there.

Comment: I'm not asking that. I already have the type of game I'm making; this is just a design element of it. @Byte56 Isn't this part of developing a game? Finding out which features would the best received is an integral part of the design process.

Comment: @Garan We're in agreement about the validity of the question. It's a valid question for game development and important to know the answer to. However, this isn't the site for such questions. Since there's no correct answer (other than try it out and see), it would just be a list of opinions about who thinks what is best. See the [FAQ] about where to ask (see the discussion oriented questions section).

Comment: Ok, fair point. I'll close this and ask this in a more appropriate location.

Answer (score 4):

Try both. I expect the difference in your code should be trivial. Play for a while with each and decide which feels better. Then recruit some others to play and see what they think.

Comment: +1 this is the answer to any "which features should I implement?" question.